# Random H18 errors on Heroku on short simple requests

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

My server on Heroku [seemingly] randomly returns H18 errors.

I use:

- Gunicorn (I tried both sync and gevent workers)
- Flask
- Flask-Restful

If I repeat the same request several times, I occasionally get an H18. I noticed that the most often I get such a response when an exception is raised in my code. I have a handler defined that returns a valid HTTP error response and most of the time it succeeds. Sometimes it fails though - for the reason that I cannot understand.

Here's how the "Bad situation" log looks like:

```
2018-03-10T17:50:51.875115+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-10 17:50:51 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] PUT /api/v1/views/270
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879035+00:00 app[web.1]: PPMException: Token expired
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879442+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879447+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879449+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879451+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879452+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879456+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879454+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879458+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879464+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879466+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 88, in decorated
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879463+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879469+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 125, in authenticate
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879468+00:00 app[web.1]:     if not self.authenticate(auth, password):
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879471+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.verify_password_callback(username, client_password)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879473+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/api_security.py", line 31, in verify_password
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879477+00:00 app[web.1]: PPMException: Token expired
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879475+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise PPMException("SECURITY_TOKEN_EXPIRED", http_code=401)
2018-03-10T17:50:51.879479+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-10T17:50:51.881229+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.189.169.232 - eyJleHAiOjE1MjA3MDQyNTAsImlhdCI6MTUyMDcwNDI0MCwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMyIsIm9yaWdpbmFsX2lzc3VlX2RhdGUiOiIyMDE4LTAzLTEwVDE3OjQ5OjI0Ljk3NTkwMCJ9.mB_NCtrGeDSq0ATs-Zl-Fg8qYRCx8YyIkjVdaLi_O6c 
[10/Mar/2018:17:50:51 +0000] "PUT /api/v1/views/270 HTTP/1.1" 401 91 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
2018-03-10T17:50:51.881448+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-10 17:50:51 +0000]     [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
2018-03-10T17:50:51.975825+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=PUT path="/api/v1/views/270" host=***-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=68b4ddb1-19b4-4753-9b3f-395c80fc777a fwd="81.164.187.197" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=106ms status=503 bytes=483 protocol=https
```

vs. how the same exception looks without H18:

```
2018-03-10T17:53:22.660154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-10 17:53:22 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] PUT /api/v1/views/270
2018-03-10T17:53:22.667461+00:00 app[web.1]: PPMException: Token expired
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669037+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669041+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669042+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669044+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669046+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669048+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669050+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669055+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669057+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669059+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669060+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669062+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 88, in decorated
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669064+00:00 app[web.1]:     if not self.authenticate(auth, password):
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669070+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/api_security.py", line 31, in verify_password
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669075+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669066+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 125, in authenticate
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669068+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.verify_password_callback(username, client_password)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669071+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise PPMException("SECURITY_TOKEN_EXPIRED", http_code=401)
2018-03-10T17:53:22.669073+00:00 app[web.1]: PPMException: Token expired
2018-03-10T17:53:22.677909+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.61.151 - eyJleHAiOjE1MjA3MDQyNTAsImlhdCI6MTUyMDcwNDI0MCwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMyIsIm9yaWdpbmFsX2lzc3VlX2RhdGUiOiIyMDE4LTAzLTEwVDE3OjQ5OjI0Ljk3NTkwMCJ9.mB_NCtrGeDSq0ATs-Zl-Fg8qYRCx8YyIkjVdaLi_O6c [10/Mar/2018:17:53:22 +0000] "PUT /api/v1/views/270 HTTP/1.1" 401 91 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
***2018-03-10T17:53:22.678478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/api/v1/views/270" host=***-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=9e22f6a9-c980-478f-9ff1-bc8bbd4fe8c7 fwd="81.164.187.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=401 bytes=483 protocol=https
2018-03-10T17:53:22.678989+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-10 17:53:22 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

The only difference I see is that in the first case I first see Gunicorn saying "Closing connection" and then the heroku router saying H18, while in the second case heroku router reports the response and then Gunicorn is closing the connection. If Gunicorn is closing connection prematurely, is there a way for me to control it from the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this figured out.
The reason seems to be that there were still request data left unread, so I added "request.stream.read()" in my error handling code.